# Oracle: call a function inside a XMLForest

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to get a value from a function `get_phone(id)` and I get the error "ORA-06572 function get_phone has out arguments". I would like to know how can I call a function inside a XMLForest command?

```
select XMLElement ("item", XMLForest(a.address AS "address",
                                      get_phone(id) AS "mobile") AS "item") from table_example a;
```

function get_phone:

```
CREATE function get_phone (id IN NUMBER) return NUMBER IS

mobile := NUMBER;

BEGIN
    select emp.mobile
    into mobile
    from employees emp
    where emp.identifier=id;

return mobile;

end get_phone;
```

I've already tried to `mobile:= get_phone(id)` on my `select`, but it doesn't work.
Can you please help me?

Comment: `ORA-06572` is only thrown when a function has an `OUT` parameter. The function you have given in the question does not have any `OUT` parameters. Please post the function that generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

The function is invalid.

- There is no `BEGIN` statement.
- The definition of `mobile` is not valid.

Try something like:

```
CREATE function get_phone (
  id IN NUMBER
) return NUMBER
IS
  mobile NUMBER;
BEGIN
  select emp.mobile
  into   mobile
  from   employees emp
  where  emp.identifier=id;

  return mobile;
end get_phone;
/
```

After you sort that out then it ought to work:

```
select XMLElement (
         "item",
         XMLForest(
           'address' AS "address",
           get_phone(1) AS "mobile"
         )
       )
from dual;
```

**Update - Select from a table rather than `DUAL`**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( mobile, identifier ) AS
SELECT 1234567, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9876543, 2 FROM DUAL;

select XMLElement (
         "item",
         XMLForest(
           'address' AS "address",
           get_phone(identifier) AS "mobile"
         )
       )
from   Employees;
```

**Results**:

```
XMLELEMENT("ITEM",XMLFOREST('ADDRESS'AS"ADDRESS",GET_PHONE(IDENTIFIER)AS"MOBILE"))
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<item><address>address</address><mobile>1234567</mobile></item>
<item><address>address</address><mobile>9876543</mobile></item>
```

Comment: Why is it invalid? Just because I forget to put the CREATE? This will not work for me...I've already tried your solution, it will return the error I described. Also notice that your solution is for one row, if my query returns more than one row it will not work.

Comment: I went by your question - the `DUAL` table will only return 1 row unless you are using something like `CONNECT BY`.

Comment: It is invalid because you forgot the `CREATE`, the `BEGIN` and the line where you define the `mobile` variable is not valid syntax.

Comment: I just would like to know how can I call a function inside XMLForest without getting that error!! How can I catch the value returned by the function?

Comment: @porthfind Updated - it works with multiple rows if the table has multiple rows.

Comment: My problem is the error ORA -06572 returned when I execute the SELECT. Because it seems I'm not catching them...

Comment: You cannot get that error with the function you have posted - it does not have any `OUT` parameters.